# MySQL Сортировка в обратном порядке

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос такого вида

```
SELECT a.id, a.author, a.txt, a.timestamp, b.log, b.em 
FROM txt_mesg a 
LEFT JOIN users b 
ON b.id = a.author 
WHERE a.tid = '".$id."' 
ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 12"
```

Сообщения выводятся в порядке убывания времени, а нужно, в порядке возрастания

Как можно произвести такую сортировку?

Comment: поменяйте `ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC` на `ORDER BY a.timestamp ASC`

Answer (score 2):

Убрать `DESC` или заменить его на `ASC` (но это не обязательно)

```
SELECT a.id, a.author, a.txt, a.timestamp, b.log, b.em FROM txt_mesg a LEFT JOIN users b ON b.id = a.author WHERE a.tid = '".$id."' ORDER BY a.timestamp LIMIT 12"
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам судя по всему надо так же выбрать 12 последних сообщений, но при этом изменить их порядок. решается еще одним уровнем select с другой сортировкой:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
   SELECT a.id, a.author, a.txt, a.timestamp, b.log, b.em 
     FROM txt_mesg a 
     LEFT JOIN users b ON b.id = a.author 
    WHERE a.tid = '".$id."' 
    ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC 
    LIMIT 12
  ) X
 ORDER BY timestamp
```